# Glassfish 3.1.2.2 and Hibernate 4.1.9

Tags: hibernate, glassfish

I'm starting new to GF3 and Hibernate. I've seen similar questions but none for these latest versions. I've also seen the add-ons in Glassfish 3.1.2.2 with the older 3.5 version of Hibernate.

I've read conflicting info on just copying all the hibernate jars into:
`glassfish3\glassfish\lib` or `glassfish3\glassfish\domains\domain1\lib`

My objective is to write a set of web services that will use hibernate to access MySQL.

Is there a specific document that illustrates how this is done?

Comment: I don't get any errors when I copy the Hibernate 4.1.9 jars to `glassfish3\glassfish\lib`. Do you get any exceptions?